# assessing code ternary operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
  console.log('Checking... ' +
    auth.isAuthenticated() ?
      `User ${auth.user.email} is authenticated` :
      'User is not authenticated!'
  );
```

If `isAuthenticated` returns false, then auth.user is undefined.
Therefore, trying to print `auth.user.email` when `isAuthenticated==false`, will result in an error.

But in my case, I only want to print `auth.user.email` when `auth.isAuthenticated==true` but I still get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

Comment: `console.log('Checking... ' +
(auth.isAuthenticated() ?
      \`User ${auth.user.email} is authenticated\` :
      'User is not authenticated!')
  );` should work.

Comment: What's the difference? Why adding braces would solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your ternary operator with `()` for it to be considered as a single value in your String concatenation :

```js
let auth = {
  isAuthenticated: () => true,
  user: {
    email: 'test'
  }
};

console.log('Checking... ' +
  (auth.isAuthenticated() ?
    `User ${auth.user.email} is authenticated` :
    'User is not authenticated!')
);
```

Comment: @Zenno It works! But why do I need () ?

Comment: We got tons of duplicates about that :-)